# OpenGL: Enabling multisampling draws messed up edges for polygons at high zoom levels

Tags: c++, opengl, multisampling

When im using this following code:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 6);
```

and then i enable multisampling, i notice that my program no longer cares about the max mip level.

Edit: It renders the last miplevels as well, that is the problem, i dont want them being rendered.

**Edit3:**
I tested and confirmed that it doesnt forget mip limits at all, so it does follow my GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL setting. ...So the problem isnt mipmap related, i guess...

**Edit2:** Screenshots, this is the world map zoomed out a lot and using low angle to make the effect shown the worst possible way, also there is rendered water plane under the map, so theres no possibility to take black pixels from anywhere else than map textures:

[alt text http://img511.imageshack.us/img511/6635/multisamplingtexturelim.png](http://img511.imageshack.us/img511/6635/multisamplingtexturelim.png)

**Edit4:** All those pics should look like the top right corner pic (just smoother edges depending on multisampling). But apparently theres something horribly wrong in my code. I have to use mipmaps, the mipmaps arent the problem, they work perfectly.

What im doing wrong, or how can i fix this?

Comment: How exactly do you enable multisampling?

Comment: by nvidia control panel, force enabled to every application

Comment: More information is needed. How does it "not care"? Textures disappearing above that level (if not provided)? Do you have GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP enabled? Include more code or a complete test case if you can.

Comment: it renders the further texture miplevels as well, in other words: it doesnt give a shit about the MAX_LEVEL

Comment: no i dont have GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP enabled, should i? im using gluBuild2DMipmaps()

Comment: hmm. thanks for the tip, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP makes it much much more faster to do mipmaps! ..but it doesnt fix the bug.

Comment: btw are there any disadvantages using GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP ? i wonder why they ever made gluBuild2DMipmaps()

Comment: gluBuild2DMipmaps existed before GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP (GL 1.4). glu is a helper library on top of GL, they don't quite live in the same world. At some point, IHVs thought they could start accelerating the mipmap generation, so they started exposing it through GL.

Comment: @Newbie Hmm, I don't get your **Edit3:**, do you mean that there isn't a problem after all?

Comment: no problem at all? did you look at the screenshots at all? there is a problem. I edited the edit3 now. also question title.

Comment: @Newbie Atleast I can't tell from the screenshots what you think the problem is. Why don't you describe in more detail what's bothering you? All I see is 6 tiny pictures with different multisampling and `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL`.

Comment: @Newbie Ok, I saw now that you changed the title of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So the problem was not TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL after all. Funny how a simple test helped figure that out.

I had 2 theories that were about the LOD being picked differently, and both of those seem to be disproved by the solid color test.

Onto a third theory then. If I understand correctly your scene, you have a model that's using a texture atlas, and what we're observing is that some polygons that should fetch from a specific item of the atlas actually fetch from a different one. Is that right ?

This can be explained by the fact that a multisampled fragment usually get sampled at the middle of the pixel. Even when that center is not inside the triangle that generated the sample. See the bottom of [this page](http://alt.3dcenter.org/artikel/multisampling_anti-aliasing/index5_e.php) for an illustration.

The usual way to get around that is called [centroid sampling](http://www.opengl.org/pipeline/article/vol003_6/) (this page has nice illustrations of the issue too). It forces the sampling to bring back the sampling point inside the triangle.

Now the bad news: I'm not aware of any way to turn on centroid filtering outside of the programmable pipeline, and you're not using it. Do you think you want to switch to get access to that feature ?

Edit to add:

Also, not using texture atlases would be a way to work around this. The reason it is so visible is because you start fetching from another part of the atlas with the "out-of-triangle" sampling pattern.

Comment: if i dont use texture atlas, i would have to bind over 200000 textures in sequence (1000-4000 unique). and that will make huge lag-fest for some cards (probably for any card). i cant use centroid sampling yet because i dont know anything about shaders yet, so i will just forget about this smooth polygon edges thing... unless there are other ways to smooth polygons?

Comment: Well, supersampling, rather than multisampling, would do the job. But its rendering cost usually makes it impractical (does 4x the pixel math).

Answer (score 1):

Check also what have you set for the MIN_FILTER:

```
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, ... );
```

Try the different settings ( a list is [here](http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~cwyman/classes/fall04-22C151/handouts/OGLmipmap.pdf) ).

However, if you're dissatisfied with the results of gluBuild2DMipmaps I advise you to look at alternatives:

- [glGenerateMipmap/glGenerateMipmapEXT](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/glGenerateMipmap.xml) (yes, it works without FBO's)
- [SGIS_generate_mipmap](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/SGIS/generate_mipmap.txt) extension (widely supported)

Especially the latter is highly customizable. And what was not mentioned, this extension is fired up by setting `GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP` to true. It is automatical so you don't need to do recalculation if data changes.

Comment: my min_filter is GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR as it should be. why GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP isnt enough for me? why use external libs for this? i cant see any difference between gluBuild2DMipmaps() and GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, just the speed.

Answer (score 0):

You should [enable multi-sampling](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=46) through your application, not the nvidia control panel, if you want your rendering to always have it. That might even fix your issue.

As for the `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL` setting being ignored when using the control panel multisampling, it sounds like a driver bug/feature. It's weird because this feature can be used to limit what you actually load in the texture (the so-called texture completeness criteria). What if you don't load the lowest mipmap levels at all ? What gets rendered ?

Edit: From the picture you're showing, it does not really look like it ignores the setting. For one thing, MAX_LEVEL=0 is different from MAX_LEVEL=6. Now, considering the noise in your textures, I don't even get why your MAX_LEVEL=6/MS off looks that clean. It *should* be noisy based on the MAX_LEVEL=16/MS off picture. At this point, I'd advise to put distinct solid colors in each mip level of your diffuse texture (and not rely on GL to build your mips), to see exactly which mip levels you're getting.

Comment: i generate the miplevels by gluBuild2DMipmaps() function. i can see it renders the miplevels that i dont want, because the color changes in the last miplevels because of blending of pixels.

Comment: well, try to load mipmaps manually instead, and don't load all of them. There is no way to tell gluBuild2DMipmaps to not load the levels, so don't use it to do the debugging. You don't even have to really load mipmaps. Just use GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL=0

Comment: when i use GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL=0, i still see ugly textures, now there is not only black pixels, but white/black pixels present, only at low angles though, but straight at top-down it looks normal. without multisampling the textures are rendered correctly.

Comment: How about some pictures ? "ugly" does not mean much.

Comment: "I don't even get why your MAX_LEVEL=6/MS off looks that clean", because the tile textures are padded.

Comment: Hum, that does not explain it though. If it were that homogeneous at level 6, then it would stay homogeneous at smaller mips. Did you try loading solid color mips ?

Comment: nope, i dont see a reason to do that, it wont fix any problems

Comment: Well, too bad. I've got a couple theories that this test could help confirm/infirm. I guess I'll let you handle it with reasons you can see.

Comment: i tested now, it does follow the MAX_LEVEL, cant see other mip levels than that... :/ now you can tell your theories.